# Accessing a combo box property inside a datagrid in wpf

Tags: wpf, combobox, datagrid

I have a datagrid which has four columns of combobox in wpf. At the starting, the first combobox is enabled. After making a selection on the first combobox, the second combobox gets enabled. I am unable to access the combobox name property in my xaml.cs file so that I can enable the next combobox column after successful selection of the first one. Can you suggest how to access the combobox property which is present inside a datagrid in my xaml.cs file ?

This is my xaml code

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn     
    Header ="Example 9">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PartIds, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" SelectedItem ="{Binding PartId,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question so that it is easier to understand the problem.

Comment: Done please see now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two columns in your `DataGrid`, the first column contains a `combobox`, and its `selecteditem` is bound to a property named `PartId`, the second column contains also a `combobox` with a `selecteditem` bound to a property named `PartId2`, your model should look something like that:

```
public class Model
{
    public string PartId { get; set; }
    public string PartId2 { get; set; }
}
```

Now, assuming your `DataGrid`'s `itemsource` is bound to an `ObservableCollection` named `DgCollection`:

```
 private ObservableCollection<Model> _dgCollection;
 public ObservableCollection<Model> DgCollection
    {
        get { return _dgCollection; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _dgCollection)) return;
            _dgCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

The second column could use a `DataTrigger` to activate its `combobox` once the `selecteditem` of the first column is set, like so:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DgCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn     
    Header ="Example 9">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PartIds, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" SelectedItem ="{Binding PartId,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn     
            Header ="Example 10">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="FirstCbx" ItemsSource="{Binding PartIds, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" SelectedItem ="{Binding PartId2,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                        <ComboBox.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PartId}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </ComboBox.Style>
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

You could generalize this to four columns easily.

Comment: Is there a way to do it from xaml.cs ?

Comment: If you mean from code behind, yes you could, but it will be longer, ugly and more complicated, what's wrong with doing that in xaml?